# Why do I get a X-Server crash on every login on a 16.04 that should be kind of stable after so many years?

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, xorg

Xubuntu 16.04 **still** crashes on every login with an XServer error on an optimus laptop with, I installed newest NVIDIA drivers from grphics ppa, but it still crashes. It seems to be this error on lanchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1659842

The bug reporting software tells me about that it might be a duplicate bug for 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1701932 - but his bug does not even exist!

It is so annoying to have these kinds of bugs on a distro that really should be clean of bugs after so many years. What cn I do to get rid of that bug on a machine that needs Ubuntu for some special reason?

Comment: The bug id is https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107226

Comment: It's marked as "resolved" but just now my ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.15  experienced yet another crash on boot with this very same error, has it so often does...